# matrices similarity and represantation matrix according to basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over the field $F$, and let $B = \{a_1 , a_2, ... , a_n \}$ be an ordered basis for $V$.
According to the theorem there is the unique linear operator $T$ on $V$ such that 
$$ T(a_i) = a_{i+1}   \  \ ; \ i = 1 , ... , n-1 $$
$$T(a_n) = 0$$
prove that $T^n = 0$, but $T^{n-1} \neq 0.$

Let $S$ be any linear operator on $V$ such that $S^n = 0$, but $S_{n-1} \neq 0$. Prove that there is an ordered basis $B'$ for $V$ such that the matrix of $S$ in the ordered basis $B'$ is the matrix of representation of $T$.

prove that if $M$ and $N$ are $n\times n$ matrices over $F$ such that $M^n = N^n = 0$, but $M^{n-1} \neq 0 \neq N^{n-1}$. 
Then $M$ and $N$ are similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's easy to see, matrix form of $T$ in the basis $B$ has the following form
   $$
   T_B=
   \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 0 & ... & 0\\
   1 & 0 & ... & 0\\
   \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
   0 & ... & 1 & 0
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$
   Now, the matrix form of $T^k$ in the basis $B$ is equal to $T^k_B$
2. If $T^{n-1}\ne 0$, then there exists $a\in V$ with $T^{n-1}(a)\ne 0$. So the system $B'=(a,T(a),...,T^{n-1}(a))$ has only non-zero elements. We can show that $B'$ is basis. Let $c_0,...,c_{n-1}\in F$ and 
   $$c_0a+c_1T(a)+...+c_{n-1}T^{n-1}(a)=0.$$
   If we apply $T^{n-1}$ to both parts of above we can obtain
   $$c_0T^{n-1}(a)=0.$$
   So, $c_0=0$. Using the same method sequentially for $T^{n-2},...,T$ we can obtain also $c_1=...=c_{n-1}=0$. So $B'$ is linearly independent over $F$ and consists of $n$ elements, so $B'$ is a basis. Now it's easy to see that the matrix  $T_{B'}$ is equal to the above matrix.
3. Let $V$ be the space of columns of the length $n$ over $F$. By the second, there exist $a,b\in V$ such that $M^{n-1}a\ne 0\ne N^{n-1}b$. So the matrix 
   $$M_a=(a,Ma,...,M^{n-1}a)$$
   is invertible and
   $$M\cdot M_a=M_a\cdot C,$$
   where $C$ is the above matrix from the first question.
   Similarly for the matrix $N$
   $$N\cdot N_b=N_b\cdot C.$$
   Now it's easy to see
   $$(N_bM_a^{-1})\cdot M\cdot (N_bM_a^{-1})^{-1}=N$$

Comment: Keep calm, and learn algebra)